# How to load data attributes in AngularJS functions?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, url, custom-data-attribute

I am playing with a website project that uses both JQuery and AngularJS. `$http` is used for the REST communication between the browser and the server. The website's URL is `localhost:8080/myproject`. Therefore, every page or resource has a path `/myproject/someresource`. In order to be able to easily construct these paths I use a data property on the `body`element:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body data-url="myproject">
</body>
```

The actual value of `data-url` is dynamically generated via JSP's `<c:url value="/" />`. Now I want to use this attribute to build some paths for the `$http` method. To this end, I use JQuery:

```js
var path = $('body').attr('data-url');
```

However, I have to wait for the end of the DOM generation, so the previous gets wrapped:

```js
var path;
$(function() {
    path = $('body').attr('data-url');
}
```

On the other hand, I have a AngularJS `$scope` function which is used for a button:

```xml
<button ng-click="foo()">click</button>
```

...

```js
var mainApp = angular.module('main', [ 'ngResource' ]);
mainApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.foo = function() {
    $http.get(path + 'folder').success(function(response) { /* do crazy stuff */ });
  };
}
```

In order to make the compilation of the angular code work it may not be wrapped inside the `$` function like the definition of `path`. Thus, `path` will not be set at the definition time of the controller. The only solution that I found was to move the definition of `foo()` inside `$()` and store `$http` in the `$scope`:

```js
mainApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.$http = $http;
}
$(function() {
    var path = $('body').attr('data-url');
    var $scope = angular.element($('main')).scope();
    var $http = $scope.$http;

    $scope.foo = function() {
      $http.get(path + 'folder').success(function(response) { /* do crazy stuff */ });
    };
}
```

Is there any clean solution for this problem? My way looks like a dirty hack...

Comment: Can't you simply use the `<base href="..." />` tag?

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to load paths dynamically in _data-url_? If there is no need to load it on this way, you could make static configuration with "plain" AngularJS...

Comment: @sp00m I can use this tag. But this will not solve the main problem that AngularJS' controllers need to be defined before the completion of the DOM setup which in turn needs to be finished before I can query the attribute via JQuery.

Comment: @arman1991 So would you just hard code `myproject` into the Javascript code? If so I would like to have this value depend on some property that is automatically changed maybe by the build system whenever the top folder name changes. Please shoot if you know how to configure it this way.

Comment: @Bastian, I posted the basic routing configuration in AngularJS, hope it will push you forward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, shame on me - I do not know why there ever were problems with the order of execution of AngularJS and JQuery but they seem to be gone. When I wrote this post I thought that AngularJS' compilation was executed before JQuery was loaded which was why I could not make use of JQuery at the definition of my controllers. Maybe I mixed something up...

However, I just checked Andy's answer and saw that his solution would work. Nevertheless. I can skip the use of global variables that he proposed and just put all my controller logic right into the controller defintion - including the JQuery call:

```js
var mainApp = angular.module('main', [ 'ngResource' ]);
mainApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.foo = function() {
    var path = $('body').attr('data-url');
    $http.get(path + 'folder').success(function(response) { /* do crazy stuff */ });
  };
});
```

It makes sense that this works since AngularJS internally already uses JQuery [(jqLite)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable with angularjs

First off, setup variable

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.path = $('body').attr('data-url');
});
```

Finally

```
var mainApp = angular.module('main', [ 'ngResource' ]);
mainApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  var path = $scope.path;
  $scope.foo = function() {
    $http.get(path + 'folder').success(function(response) { /* do crazy stuff */ });
  };
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Your solution works, however, it tackled not the original problem - see my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for configuring the routes and [constants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) to save your URL and then inject it in module.

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .constant("myConfig", {
        "url": "http://localhost",
        "port": "8080"
    })
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/somesource', { 
                templateUrl: 'views/page.html',
                controller: 'myController'
            })
            .when('/somesource2', { 
                templateUrl: 'views/page2.html',
                controller: 'myController2'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    })
    .controller('myController', function (myConfig) {
        // Your functions...
    });
```

This is example where config could be injectable at any part of your application.
On this way you can for every path manage the url of your page and which controller will be used for that path...

Maybe this solution can be helpful for you.